# How do I return data from multiple APIs to display on one page in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I have two API endpoints that I am retrieving data from and I want to display the number of records in each. This is my code so far, which sort of works, and test6tg5ing the API in Postman returns the correct data -

```js
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resSeven = await axios('http://localhost:5000/api/7daycheck');
    const resThirty = await axios('http://localhost:5000/api/30daycheck');
    setOrders({ seven: resSeven.data, thirty: resThirty.data });
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Now, When I add `console.log(orders.seven);` , the console shows this -

[image: Console output]

So when I add the line `<p>{orders.seven.length}</p>` in my JSX code it throws the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". What's going on?

Comment: First of all, you initialize orders as an array (`const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);`) then set it to an object (`setOrders({ seven: resSeven.data, thirty: resThirty.data });`); it does not make a lot of sense. Anyway, the issue is due to the fact that `orders.seven` is `undefined` until you get back the response from your fetch call. If you change `<p>{orders.seven.length}</p>` with `<p>{orders && orders.seven && orders.seven.length}</p>` you should not see that error anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial state of `orders` is an empty array:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
```

Which has no property called `seven`.  So when you try to display that state:

```
<p>{orders.seven.length}</p>
```

You'll get an error.  If the resulting value for `orders` *isn't* an array then you shouldn't set it to one to begin with.  Give it the structure you expect:

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState({ seven: [] });
```

This would initialize it to an object with a property called `seven` which itself is an empty array.  Then the `length` will correctly be `0`.